# Changing Kendo Grid model and manually saving it

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'd like to manually save Kendo Grid's item, but before that I should be able to change the model.

As far as I know there are two ways to change a model: 1. in `OnEdit` event. 2. in `OnSave` event.

There required information isn't available before inserting a new row, therefore I'm not able to use `OnEdit` event.

On the other hand, for saving that item there are also two ways: 1. firing `sync` method of `DataSource`. 2. firing `saveChanges` method of the Grid which seems to just fire the `sync` method. Unfortunately, none of these events fires `OnSave` event!! `saveChanges` method fires `saveChanges` event but model is not accessible in this event.

Any suggestion and work-around is welcome!

Comment: Show your scenario or better fiddle

Comment: You can use Kendo Window for values to edit, save by method then refresh the grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that actually there is a third way to save Kendo Grid: `SaveRow`. This method will fire `save` event of the Gird, just like when user clicks save button.

`$('gridId').data().kendoGrid.saveRows();`

So with above code, I can keep my current handler unchanged, and I can change the model in `save` event handler… .

Answer (score 1):

OnGridEdit - fires when user clicks edit, so if you want to display some default values when user clicks edit you can do it here. you dont have to call save changes as grid is not bound yet.

OnGridSave -one option fires when user clicks update, you can do

```
e.preventDefault(); e.model.field = "changevalue"; grid.savechanges;
```

second option, when user clicks update, it calls the controller method, where you can modify the model and send the updated modified model

OnRequestEnd - if you dont want to update on the server, just want to display the modified values to the user, you can do in this event. here you will get all the records, you have to loop through and update the values

```
  if (e.type == "update") {}
```

Comment: Sorry Veena, it doesn't address my problem, I've stated that information isn't available in `edit` event and that I need to save the grid myself, I'm not living it up to user. And I want to change the model, not just pushing some updates.

Comment: post some code to better understand your requirement so that we can help better